# Mobile SDK plugins customization using Sumsub does not work for Android

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, customization

I was faced with the task of customizing the KYC design for iOS and Android. We use Sumsub on the project. When I did everything according to the documentation, iOS started working, but Android didn’t. I'm using version 1.20.3 @sumsub/react-native-mobilesdk-module

Here is the code of how I customized it

```
export const launchSNSMobileSDK = (
  accessToken: string,
  onSuccess: () => void,
  onError: (errorStatus: KycStatus) => void,
  type: VerifyType,
) => {
  const snsMobileSDK = SNSMobileSDK.init(accessToken, () => getAccessToken(type))
    .withDebug(true)
    .withTheme(theme)
    .withLocale('en') // Optional, for cases when you need to override the system locale
    .withHandlers({
      // check the returned event status and if its status is Approved - close the SDK
      onStatusChanged: event => {
        if (event.newStatus === 'Approved') {
          setTimeout(() => snsMobileSDK.dismiss(), 2000);
        }
      },
    })
    .build();

  snsMobileSDK
    .launch()
    .then(result => {
      if (result.status === 'Approved') {
        onSuccess();
      }
      if (result.status === 'Failed' || result.status === 'FinallyRejected') {
        onError(KycStatus.Error);
      }
      if (result.status === 'TemporarilyDeclined') {
        onError(KycStatus.Temporarily);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      onError(KycStatus.ServerError);
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

Here is the theme object:

```
{
  "universal": {
    "metrics": {
      "buttonBorderWidth": 0,
      "fieldCornerRadius": 10,
      "buttonCornerRadius": 24
    },
    "colors": {
      "backgroundCommon": "#1d182e",
      "backgroundNeutral": "#2d283c",
      "primaryButtonBackground": "#553d94",
      "primaryButtonBackgroundHighlighted": "#2d283c",
      "primaryButtonBackgroundDisabled": "#2d283c",
      "secondaryButtonBackground": "#2d283c",
      "secondaryButtonContent": "#FFF",
      "fieldBackground": "#2d283c",
      "contentStrong": "#FFFFFFC2",
      "contentNeutral": "#FFF",
      "fieldContent": "#94A0B8"
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to set only that fields that are supported for Android, and it did not help me